# How to verify the SQLite column index once the indexing is done in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sqlite, ios4

I have an iPhone app where in 18000 entries in the database. So I needed to create index for the column using which I search the data from the database.

Now once the indexing is created, how can we verify whether the index is properly created or not?

What should be done to verify that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Sqlite Manager (plugin in Mozilla Firefox) to access the Sqlite database. I found that we can see the indexes that we have created. For that we can use the `sqlite_master` table.

`Select * from sqlite_master` would give all tables and indexes that are created.